# building the develop and prod projects from same branch

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

HI Actually I want to use only one branch for building both dev and prod by maven which have different configurations for dev and prod.
I have created a folder called config and created sub folders called dev and prod containing their configurations and files.

Now , generally we used to have master and develop branch and we use to build server like
mvn -U clean install -P APIServer.

Now the requirement is like for dev properties , the files need to copy from the config folder to their respective places.
mvn -U clean install -PDEV APIServer

For prod :
mvn -U clean install -PPROD APIServer.
prod properties from the config folders should go to their respective places and build production server.

How to implement this. I am totally confused regarding the implementation.

Comment: First question: Why do you have different dependencies for DEV and PROD because that would mean you are testing in DEV something different than you are using in prod which makes no sense from my point of view...

Comment: different dependencies means different services, like test db is different from prod db , we will be configuring these in different files right. I was mentioning that

Comment: A service is based on a dependency? From my point of view it is more a property..That a test db is a different location meaning having url/username/passwort is different which means having a different property file for that...but not a different dependency...that sounds wrong from a design perspective... But the code must be the same...otherwise you are not testing the correct things...

Comment: Its my mistake. I mean configurations not dependencies.

Comment: Configuration shouldn't be packaged somehow only provided by the environment where you are running so that would mean no profile needed? In particular if you do a `install` ? If you have tests they should use dev by default...and testing against with unit/integration tests is by definition a bad idea...